# Assign each element of a vector to the last element of several other vectors in one line in R

Tags: r

How to assign each element of a vector to the last element of several other vectors in one line ?
Or more generally, same question but replace "last element" with "i-th element".

```r
# Problem : assign each element of the root vector 
# to the last element of the target vectors
root <- c(5, 1, 2)
targ1 <- targ2 <- targ3 <- 1:4

# Solution 
i = length(targ1)
targ1[i] <- root[1]
targ2[i] <- root[2]
targ3[i] <- root[3]

# The previous solution works, but it's too verbose. 
# Is it possible to achieve this in one line or so ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the objects in a `list` and `replace`

```
list2env(Map(\(x, y) replace(x, i, y), mget(ls(pattern = 'targ')), 
    root), .GlobalEnv)
```

-output

```
> targ1
[1] 1 2 3 5
> targ2
[1] 1 2 3 1
> targ3
[1] 1 2 3 2
```

Comment: Very good, I was not even expecting a solution with a automated way of getting the target vectors - with `ls(pattern = 'targ'))`) - but I take it

Comment: The crucial function here is `list2env`

Comment: @Julien I would keep objects in list instead of creating objects in env.  Yes, the `list2env` will update the objects in the global env

Comment: Just in case the *several other vectors* don't have the same length: `Map(\(x, y) replace(x, length(x), y), mget(ls(pattern = 'targ')), root)`

Comment: @GKi thanks you are right.  I used `i` as the OP defined it earlier